# Python информация из строки

Tags: python, serial

Пытаюсь получить информацию из строки.

Первым делом у меня был код, служащий для отправки через serial "t" и я получал 3 строки с данными.

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate = 115200, timeout = 1)

def send_serial():
 cde = "t\r"
 port.write(cde.encode('ascii'))
 print port.read(9999)
```

вот что выводилось в консоль

```
HDMI IN CH1  1920x1080p60   RGB                                                                                                                      
HDMI OUT     1920x1080p60   RGB  
HDMI IN CH2  1920x1080p60   RGB
```

я хочу получить каждое значение после `CH1`, `CH2` и `OUT` и без `RGB`.

Для начала попытался с помощью такого кода:

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate = 115200, timeout = 1)

def send_serial():
 cde = "t\r"
 port.write(cde.encode('ascii'))
 f = port.read(9999)
 for line in f:
   if line[0:14] == 'HDMI IN CH1':
      length = len(line)
      j = line[12: length -1]
 print j
```

Но все что я получаю, это пустую строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить желаемую информацию из строки:

```
import re

results = re.findall(r'(\d+)x(\d+)p(\d+)', port.read(9999))
```

`for line in f` в вашем коде вводит в заблуждение. В вашем случае `f` это последовательность байтов и соответственно цикл итерирует побайтово, а не построчно.

Comment: а как с помощью вашего кода, разделить значения 1920 и тд в разные переменные? Я его не понимаю.

Comment: @Insider если не знаете как со списками в Питоне работать, то выполните `print(results)`, укажите какие конкретно значения в какие переменные вы хотите положить и опубликуйте в виде нового вопроса (код с serial не обязательно в этом случае приводить, достаточно если вывод `print(results)` показан)

Comment: Вот новый вопрос - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566272/19108

Comment: @Insider "не все результаты" и "не понимаю" это разные вопросы—старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос. Для ввода в вопросе, регулярное выражение все результаты возвращает. Если возможен разный ввод, то приведите все варианты, которые вы хотите поддерживать в вопросе (с пробелами или без, со всеми цифрами, с пропущенными данными итд)—должно быть легко поправить regex.

Comment: вывода разного не существует, вопрос по моему мнение больше не требуется уменьшать, к сожалению нечего там уменьшать

Comment: @Insider  1- конечно есть, будьте внимательней: в одном случае нет пробелов (строка а этом вопросе) `1920x1080p60`, в другом случае есть пробел `640x 480p60` <-- после `x` пробел (поэтому `findall()` для строки из другого вопроса не все результаты и возвращает, потому что формат другой). Регулярное выражение легко поправить, если это единственная вариация в ожидаемом формате. 2- у вас в новом вопросе сразу несколько проблем, поэтому конечно его можно разбить (не нужно весь код без разбора приводить, старайтесь изолировать ошибки).