# Python работа со строками и со списком

Tags: python, serial

В прошлом вопросе задавал, как получить значение из вывода из serial.

В этоге получился вот такой код:

```
import serial
import re
import time

port = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate = 115200, timeout = 1)

def send_serial():
 cde = "t\r"
 port.write(cde.encode('ascii'))
 results = re.findall(r'(\d+)x(\d+)p(\d+)', port.read(9999))
 print results
```

получаю в этоге такое `[('1920', '1080', '60'), ('1920', '1080', '60')]`

Тут не хватает двух значений

```
HDMI IN CH1  1920x1080p60   RGB                                                                                                                      
HDMI IN CH2   640x 480p60   RGB                                                                                                                      
HDMI OUT     1920x1080p60   RGB
```

Также интересует, как отформатировать вывод в разные переменные.
Ну а также интересно как получить данные с такого списка

```
                 HDMI IN CH1    VP IN CH1                                                                                                            
interlaced                 0            -                                                                                                            
hstart                   148          141                                                                                                            
active width            1920         1920                                                                                                            
vstart                    36           36                                                                                                            
active height           1080         1080                                                                                                            
total width             2200         2199                                                                                                            
total height            1125         1120                                                                                                            
field rate                60           60
piclk              148507000    147840000
hsync                     44            -
vsync                      5            -
colorspace       RGB LIMITED            -

                 HDMI IN CH2    VP IN CH2
interlaced                 0            -
hstart                    48        65529
active width             640            0
vstart                    33         8191
active height            480            0
total width              800          799
total height             525          523
field rate                60           60
piclk               25203000     25104000
hsync                     96            -
vsync                      2            -
colorspace       RGB LIMITED            -

                    HDMI OUT       VP OUT
active width               -         1920
active height              -         1080
total width             2200         2200
total height            1125         1125
active width               -         1920
active height              -         1081
color in                 RGB            -
color out            RGB 444   YUV444/RGB
hsync                      -           44
vsync                      -            5
```

желательно также все сохранить значения такие как "hstart" и "vstart" в отдельные переменные.
Название значений может быть примерно таким, `hdmi_in_chn1_1, hdmi_in_chn1_2, hstart_1, hstart_2` и тд.

Comment: я вижу три вопроса здесь: 1- "как исправить `findall()` чтобы все значения возвращались" 2- "отформатировать вывод в разные переменные" (в какие конкретно переменные?) 3- "как получить данные из (новой в другом формате) строки." Старайтесь ограничивать ваши вопросы *одним* вопросом, чтобы ваши вопросы имели больше шансов помочь также кому-нибудь другому (если вы просто все ваши текущие проблемы с программированием в форму с вопросом будете помещать, то никому кроме вас ответы на такие вопросы не помогут).

Comment: @jfs прошу прощения, надеюсь в последний раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results = re.findall(r'(\d+)x(\d+)p(\d+)', port.read(9999))
```

Замените на

```
 results = re.findall(r'(\d+)x\s*(\d+)p(\d+)', port.read(9999))
```

Чтобы получить данные со списка нужно

1. Разбить на строки
2. Разбить строку по 2-3 пробелам
3. Обрезать лишние пробелы в элементах массива.
4. Если элементов в массиве 2 - это заголовок таблицы, если 3 - данные
5. Profit